# Hidden condition to all possible queries

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'd like to hide selecting objects not by rewriting all SQL queries but by more simple way.

So, I'd like to add a rule (or something else) to a database for a particular table. E.g. if we delete a user from a website we execute something like the next:

```
UPDATE user_common SET is_deleted='t' WHERE user_id=1234
```

And there are no need to rewrite all existing queries about users, the condition is hidden:

```
SELECT first_name, second_name FROM user_common WHERE coins>200
```

The SELECT above will be executed with a hidden condition, e.g.:

```
SELECT first_name, second_name FROM user_common WHERE coins>200 AND is_deleted!='t'
```

How to make it working?

Comment: This is how many systems work, e.g. statecode in Dynamics CRM.  The simplest way to make the condition "hidden" is to use views to present the tables, i.e. never query the database directly but always via a view with the "is_deleted != 't'" condition embedded.

Comment: @RichardHansell: In fact, this is more or less how deletion works in Postgres itself - deleting a row writes your transaction id to a hidden column, and subsequent queries check the column to filter these rows out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want with a view.

```
create view v_table
    select uc.*
    from user_common uc
    where is_deleted <> 't';
```

The key is that references to the table really need to change to the view.  One way to do this is by renaming the table and then creating a view with the same name:

```
alter table user_common to base_user_common;

create view user_common as
    select uc.*
    from user_common uc
    where is_deleted <> 't';
```

Comment: It will do the job for `SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE` but wont work as desired for `DELETE`.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: that will work for `DELETE` just as well: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e078b/1

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know that it will delete the record but is not the desired behavior. It will not update the record with `is_deleted='t'` as described in the question.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: ah, right. I guess that could be done using a delete rule.

Comment: Will *SELECT* work as fast as *SELECT* from usual table or there will be much slower?

Comment: @sergzach . . . You should always check such things on your data and on your system, but I would expect Postgres to be as efficient using the view as using the base table.

Answer (score 3):

As [@Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25361960/1104979) pointed out in his answer, you can use a view to hide the deleted rows, and (as of Postgres 9.3, at least) changes to this view will be automatically applied to the underlying table.

But you can take this a step further, transforming `DELETE`s on the view into `UPDATE`s of the base table's `is_deleted` flag, using Postgres' [rule system](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createrule.html). If you exclude `is_deleted` itself from the view, it should be pretty much indistinguishable from a "normal" table.

```
CREATE TABLE user_common_base
(
  user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name TEXT,
  second_name TEXT,
  coins INTEGER,
  is_deleted BOOLEAN DEFAULT false
);

CREATE VIEW user_common AS
  SELECT
    user_id,
    first_name,
    second_name,
    coins
  FROM user_common_base
  WHERE NOT is_deleted;

CREATE RULE user_common_delete AS
ON DELETE TO user_common
DO INSTEAD
  UPDATE user_common_base
  SET is_deleted = true
  WHERE id = OLD.id;
```